# How can I configure my ADSL modem and Home PC to be able to access from external?

Tags: networking, software-rec, remote-desktop, dynamic-ip

I tried to do it some years ago without success. If I remember well there were more software involved, maybe now the process is easier.

Practically I have an **ADSL connection with dynamic IP** and I would like to access my home PC from elsewhere, taking in account all **security issues**.

I would like to control the screen and browsing hard disk content from remote.

I have **Windows XP** at Home and I have also the problem that my connection reset more times (3/4) per day **randomly** and the IP address changes every time.

Can you please indicate me the simplest solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on the answer by TheTXI

Using a service like [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com) you create a new account which will provide you with a unqiue Url, for example myhome.dyndns.org.

Depending on whether you have an ADSL Router or Modem the process differs slightly. When using an ADSL router you need to configure the Dynamic IP settings on the router to point to your new DynDNS URL using the username and password you supplied. This will ensure that every time the line resets the new IP is given to DynDNS. This process normally takes about 20 minutes. If your using an ADSL Modem you will need to download seperate software to do this.

When using an ADSL router you also need to setup Port Forwarding. This will allow the router to send data for a particular port, either VNC or RDP to your machine. To use this I recommend either giving the machine you want to connect to a Static IP directly or using DHCP assigned static IP based on Mac address.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using

- [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) (will take care of the dynamic IP problem by always updating with the new IP when it is given)
- [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) (used for the remote desktop connection)

You could also use other software products to achieve the same results, but this is typically the most popular combo.

Answer (score 1):

DynDNS has become paid now. No-ip.com offers the service for free. You can see a detailed tutorial to access your computer connected via a wired ADSL modem + wireless router from external network at https://himanshuforhpc.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/) by [Fog Creek](http://www.fogcreek.com/), although I do not know how long a single 'session' lasts for.

Comment: That looks more like a GoToMeeting/WebEx competitor than a traditional Remote Desktop/VNC solution.

Comment: Using Copilot (and maybe even GoToMeeting/WebEx), you don't need to use dynamic ip address services. Copilot I beleive is based upon VNC.

Answer (score 0):

I just mentioned this on [another SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/7257/how-can-i-remotely-login-to-my-windows-pc-using-my-mac/7865#7865): but [Log Me In](https://secure.logmein.com/home.asp?lang=en) is very easy to install and use - just create a free account, download, and run the installer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

save all the hassle, get a permanent IP from your ISP for very cheap
and set port forwarding or a demilitarized zone (DMZ) with your router.