# How can I remotely login to my Windows PC using my Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop

What is the easiest way to do a remote login over a local network, ala Remote Desktop?

(preferably using something free)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RDP client](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx) for Mac

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! This is *exactly* what I was looking for!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 5):

There is also [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/index.html) which is an open source RDP Client for the Mac. I find the UI for managing sessions of the Microsoft client to be a little bizarre. CoRD is better in that respect.

Comment: I've used both, CoRD is more functional to me than the MS client.

Comment: I've been using the code straight from svn. It's stable and adds some features not yet available in the beta -- sortable and searchable server list, keyboard shortcuts. See info at http://cord.sourceforge.net/development.html

Answer (score 2):

All good options above, I just want to add [Log Me In](https://secure.logmein.com/home.asp?lang=en). Very easy to install and use - just create a free account, download, and run the installer. I hope this helps.

Comment: I use LogMeIn extensively. But I was asking this question with regard to local network access - I probably should have mentioned that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use VNC. There's a plethora of servers and clients available for a multitude of platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is (the Free for Personal Use) [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).  This can work over LAN, as well as over the internets.

You can also set it up on Windows to run as a service.