# Best way to screen share between a PC Desktop & Mac Laptop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-control, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remotely login to my Windows PC using my Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/7257/how-can-i-remotely-login-to-my-windows-pc-using-my-mac)

I have a 15" Macbook Pro & a dual-screen Vista desktop.  There are a few programs I occasionally use that are Windows-only.  I'd like to be able to connect remotely to my PC from my Mac.  I know of VNC, but that's a poor experience given the drastic difference in screen size between the two systems.

In a prefect world, I'd be able to connect remotely from the mac, go full-screen, and everything would sized for my 15" inch screen.

Is this possible?  I'm currently running Vista (ugh) on the desktop, but I'm open to upgrading to Windows 7 (although there's a million versions).

Update: To be clear, I want to control my PC desktop from my Mac laptop, in a way that address the different screen sizes.

Comment: Out of many other duplicates, the one with the best title: "How can I remotely login to my Windows PC using my Mac?" at http://superuser.com/questions/7257/how-can-i-remotely-login-to-my-windows-pc-using-my-mac

Comment: Grah.  None of those address the disparity in screen size between the two systems, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

To control the PC from the Mac you can use Microsoft's [Remote Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx)

If you want to do the reverse, you can use VNC as you said but I prefer to use [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com) for this as I don't have to worry about network configurations or anything. It works inside the browser but you can bump it to full screen.

Answer (score 1):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx) is also very nice (and free). You can set it up that it only works inside your LAN. This way it does not connect to the master server.