# Which VNC for Mac to WinXP Home control?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remotely login to my Windows PC using my Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/7257/how-can-i-remotely-login-to-my-windows-pc-using-my-mac)

I've got a MacBook and a Windows XP Home machine.  I'd like to be able to connect into the XP machine from the Mac over VNC, but not through the Web method, where performance seems to be a bit iffy.

I've done some research, and it seems everyone is interested in the XP->Mac connection, where I'm looking to go in the other direction.

Is there a free VNC Server out there that will let me accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VNC server runs on whichever computer you want to connect **to**, so you would be looking for a Windows VNC server.  I recommend [UltraVNC.](http://www.uvnc.com)  It also includes a VNC client if you later decide you need this.

Most people recommend [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) as a Mac VNC client.  If you later decide you want to connect to the Mac as well, Mac OS X includes a built-in VNC server you can enable through System Preferences → Sharing → Screen Sharing.

Both UltraVNC and Chicken of the VNC are cost-free and open source.

Comment: So the clients and servers don't have to match?  I suppose a dope slap may be in order for me. :-)

Comment: Some VNC distributions have added their own proprietary extensions, but for the most part they are compatible.